# how i use there preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I use one forum script. It works well with the script below in php5.4. But, with php5.5 problems arise as in the picture below. 
[error http://oi60.tinypic.com/k0hyfq.jpg](http://oi60.tinypic.com/k0hyfq.jpg)

Full-sized image can be found here: http://oi60.tinypic.com/k0hyfq.jpg.

Code:

```
// replace RE: RE: RE: by RE[3]:
$this->subject = preg_replace('/(^RE: RE\[)(\d+)(?=\]:)/ie', '"RE[".(\\2+1)', $this->subject);
$this->subject = preg_replace('/^(RE: RE:(?: RE:)+)/ie', '"RE[".substr_count("\\1", "RE:")."]:"', $this->subject);
```

Comment: What do you want to know about the callback? The PHP documentation should give you enough information about preg_replace_callback(). Please let us know what problems have you run into.

Comment: i use one forum script. It works well with this script php5.4.
But, with php5.5 problems arise as in the picture below.

http://i60.tinypic.com/k0hyfq.jpg

Comment: Let's start with a simple question: Do you know anything about programming? Because from the sounds of your question, you have no idea how the code you're using actually works...

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know, unfortunately, nothing much.

Answer (score 0):

we've changed the code as follows. Currently there is no problem

Code:

```
$tempSubject = $this->subject;
                    $tempSubject = preg_replace_callback('/(^RE: RE\[)(\d+)(?=\]:)/i', function($match) {
                        return "RE[".$match[2];
                        }, $tempSubject);           
                    $tempSubject = preg_replace_callback('/^(RE: RE:(?: RE:)+)/i', function($match) {
                        return "RE[".substr_count($match[1], "RE:")."]:";
                        }, $tempSubject);

                    $this->subject = $tempSubject;
```